# How to install the newest Mono?

Tags: package-management, ppa, debian

I want to install the newest version of Mono on my Ubuntu 13.10 installation, but obviously it requires me to download a lot of packages from the Debian website, which is not ideal as it is hard to fix up dependencies. (+ They'll all be marked as manually installed)

I am aware I can install mono from source but I'd prefer not to.

How do I add a Debian PPA to my package managers, so I can just install it with Aptitude or APT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all.

### Do not mix different repositories.

Ubuntu and Debian packages have differences in the way they are built. You may have unexpected results if you don't know what are you doing. The best way to install these packages are:

1. Waiting for Ubuntu to catch up with upstream.
2. Using the Ubuntu's mono PPA.
3. Chroot or create a virtual machine with Debian
4. Build from sources.

Those are the recommended methods to do things around. If you want to mess with your system, please do so, but don't argue that we didn't tell you if something goes wrong. Actually Murphy's Law says something will go wrong.

Comment: The problem is that Ubuntu's Mono PPA is strongly outdated and it has been for a while, doesn't seem like it's going to catch up soon. A Virtual Machine would work but it'd be an extra hassle as I need to use it specifically on Ubuntu. The sources I have tried before but that just went terribly wrong. I guess I will look further into that then though, thanks for your input.

Comment: @JeroenBollen and chrooting? BTW, you can make your own PPA, it will be a hassle the first time but if you always need to go for the last it will be easier.

Comment: @JeroenBollen you can also build the Debian sources from there https://launchpad.net/debian/sid/+source/mono, just download the 3 sources files, use dpkg-source -x *.dsc and build it like Debian source.

Answer (score 1):

**No PPA is needed.**

Ubuntu [Official Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mono&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all) has all those needed.

There is a Ubuntu Mono Development guide at [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MonoDevelopmentHowto).

But it is a older article. So the command mentioned at there should be changed as following.

```
sudo apt-get install mono-mcs libgtk2.0-cil libgtksourceview2-2.0-cil monodevelop monodoc-base mono-tools-gui mono-complete
```

Comment: The problem with the Ubuntu version was it runs only 2.9, and I need 3.x...